# Regexp: Removing commas from numbers in text

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove commas from numbers in a text, and I have the following:

```
/\d\u002c\d/
```

But this didnt work, and I'm not sure why (looking for a number, a comma, then a number). 
Overall, I want to detect: (number) km, so that I'll convert it to meters. With the help of others, this is what I have for detecting a number (works on decimals):

```
/\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+ *km/gi
```

Is it easier to modify the above or should I first remove the commas from all numbers?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide your input and expected output.

Comment: If I have the following in the text, I want to detect it: 124,000 km (I'm doing the rest of the replacement part in my code, I just want to learn how to detect this specific pattern)
I want the number as 124000, so that I'll process it.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `\d,\d` regex for replace?

Comment: But the number might contain more than one comma, such as 124,123,515
Will this work as well?

Comment: Yes you can do: `input.replace(/(\d),(?=\d)/g, '$1');`

Comment: Does `km` always have to follow the numbers?

Comment: Not necessarily but I only want to process those that do. 
The above works neatly, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to go is to match the parts around the comma and then remove it:

```
var input = '124,000 km';
input.replace(/(\d+),(\d+\s?km)/g, '$1$2');
```

Comment: input.replaceAll(/(\d+),(\d+\s?km)/g, '$1$2');
would be better if the string has multi comma

Answer (score 1):

For a trimmed list of numbers each on its own line, this works for me:

```
(\d*),(\d+)/($1)($2)
```

Note that the global flag should be active so that the regex keeps on going if there are multiple groups of comma separated digits.

For these values:

```
1
10
100
1000
1,000
10,000
10000
1,200,000,000,000,999
```

the regex yields

```
1
10
100
1000
1000
10000
10000
1200000000000999
```

Tested [here.](https://regex101.com/r/N8i5Oa/1/)

Comment: for input "foo,123" the output is "foo123"

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to remove commas from numbers only. but must not remove commas which are placed next to a letter.
The proper way to solve this is with regex lookarounds:

```
r'(?<=\d)(,)(?=\d)'
```

input: "1,2,3,4" -> output: "1234"
input: "1,20,30 F,40" -> output: "12030 F,40"
input: "1,20,30 40,F" -> output: "12030 40,F"
input: "99,20, bla" -> output: "9920, bla"
input: "abc12,34efg" -> output: "abc1234efg"

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "124,000";
console.log(str.replace(',', ''));
```

Comment: That will remove all commas, not just commas from within numbers